# Как защитить виртуальную функцию от переопределения в дочернем классе в cpp?

Tags: наследование, qt, c++, функции

Запретить переписывать виртуальную функцию?
я понимаю, что чисто языковых возможностей нет. Но может какие изящные трюки, использование qt-возможностей (в qt-проекте и хочу использовать), предпроцессоры, метапрограммирование и т.п.

```
class Executor
{
public:
    void run()
    {
        //some code
        runVirtual();
        //some code
    }
private:
    virtual void runVirtual() = 0;
};
//==========================================================
class ExecutorClassic : public Executor
{
    private:
    virtual void runVirtual()
    {
        //some classic action
    }
};
//=============================================================
class ExecutorBranchA : public Executor
{
    public:

    private:
    //child classes should not use this function any more (final)
    virtual void runVirtual()
    {
        runAsync();
    }

    void runAsync()
    {       
        //some code
        ::someAsyncRunFunction(runAsyncVirtual);
        //some code
    }
    //child classes should use this func instead
    virtual void runAsyncVirtual() = 0;

};
```

Comment: Виртуальная функция ведь на то и нужна, чтобы ее переопределять. Может, стоит вообще тогда отказаться от нее в заголовочном файле и сделать ее свободной и перенести в файл реализации?

Comment: @asianirish это как? Вот так что ли? 

class Base 
{
public :
   virtual void f() 
   {
       cout << "base" << endl;
   };
};

class Derived : Base 
{
public :
   void f()  
   {
       cout << "derived" << endl;
   };      
};

тогда f() в классе Derived все равно останется виртуальной, несмотря на то, что вы не указали это явно

Comment: нет, мне нужно чтоб я не мог переопределить DerivedDerived::f(), то есть наоборот, чтоб Derived::f() ПЕРЕСТАЛА быть виртуальной. Или чтоб вообще откомпелироваться не дал, как в с++11, или чтоб какой-эксепшн вызвал

Comment: если вы объявили функцию виртуальной в предке, то она останется виртуальной и в потомках. Более того, совершенно непонятно, зачем вам нужно сделать виртуальную функцию впоследствии невиртуальной

Comment: @asianirish, а **зачем** все это нужно? 

Вы уверены, что количество ошибок использования класса уменьшится или им станет проще пользоваться?

Чем больше в системе накручено, тем более вероятно появление *тонких, логических* ошибок в программах.

О KISS принципе слышали?

Comment: об объективной актуальности потребности говорит хотя бы то, что final вошла в c++11. Особенной накрученности то и не вижу просто с этим программа станет лучше, а без этого надо будет постоянно "не забывать" в дочерних классах не переопределять вирт. PS о кисс: "Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler." 
- Albert Einstein

Comment: @asianirish я правильно понимаю, что все ваши многочисленные пространные рассуждения сводятся к вопросу, можно ли делать final-функции не только в C++11, но и в более ранних стандартах?

Comment: С *but not simlper* трудно не соглситься.

Только смотрите, чтобы все новые добавки (и их активное использование) окончательно не завели кресты в нишу языка для кучки "истинных знатоков" или языка не для *написания*, а для *описания* программ (характерно, например, для Ады).

Кстати, а что, все программеры прямо-таки неудержимо стремяться к наследованию от какого-либо класса и переопределению его методов?

Comment: да, каким-нибудь хитрым трюком. между прочим к этому сводится не пространные рассуждения, а прямая и ясная формулировка вопроса (см. наверху страницы), а рассуждения пошли как ответы на задаваемые вопросы
(по поводу стандарта) не знаю все ли программеры, но Комитет Стандартизации C++ работает с предложениями программеров, и если бы их не было, то не стали бы этого вводить. А что до "элитизации" плюсов, то да, это было бы не желательно. Но и развивать надо, а то привратится не в Аду, а в какой нибудь Вижл-Бейсик будущего.

Comment: @asianirish, я думаю, что даже если такие трюки есть, то наверняка они будут настолько зубодробительны, что окажутся злом еще большим, чем необходимость внимательно следить за переопределением функций в потомках. Вероятно, можно сделать что-нибудь с помощью макросов препроцессора и директив условной компиляции, но скорее всего это будет нечто жуткое. Впрочем, на C++ я профессионально не пишу, люди, знакомые с этим языком лучше, могут поправить

Comment: А нужно ли вам наследование? Может быть, тот класс, потомкам которого надо запретить перекрытие метода, не обязан быть наследником базового класса? (Если да, со старой версией C++ вы в тупике, `virtual` в базовом классе «заражает» все порождённые классы.) Расскажите, чего вы хотите добиться на более высоком уровне: может быть, вы выбрали неправильный путь с самого начала.

Comment: @VladD добавил в правке вопроса кода, возможно он пояснит идею для чего это нужно. Если есть другие пути воплощения вместо финализации витр. функции будет хорошо

Comment: @asianirish: Понял вашу проблему. Может быть, это вам поможет: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface

---
Попробуйте сделать так, чтобы метод был невиртуальным, но вызывал фиксированную функцию у внутреннего объекта (на который у базового класса есть указатель). Принимайте указатель на него в конструкторе. Для разных производных классов используйте разный внутренний объект (например, производный). Для цепочки, в которой надо прекратить наследование, зафиксируйте внутренний объект.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В С++11 появилась возможность помечать виртуальные функции модификатором final, что не позволяет переопределять их в классах-потомках. Аналогом является sealed в C#. Выглядит так:

```
class Base 
{
public :
   virtual void f() 
   {
       cout << "base" << endl;
   };
};

class Derived : Base  
{
public :
   virtual void f() final 
   {
       cout << "derived" << endl;
   };      
};

class SecondDerived : Derived 
{
public :
   virtual void f() // ошибка: переопределение функции, помеченной в предке как final
   {
       cout << "second derived" << endl;
   };   
};
```

Также стоит отметить, что в том же стандарте появилось и слово override. Синтаксис аналогичен синтаксису для final. По смыслу же оно похоже на аналог в C# (если вы с ним знакомы), но в силу причин, связанных с обратной совместимостью, не может быть таким строгим, и применять его можно "по желанию".

Comment: В смысле не может быть строгим? Можно в опциях компилятора включить ошибку.

Comment: опция компилятора, которая запретит писать переопределяемые методы без слова override? Какая?

Answer (score 3):

Про `final` в С++11 уже сказали.

В С++03 можно проделать трюк, описанный с [этой статье](http://www.kabit.ru/ru/post/C_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0__%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_1_Final_class.html)

Answer (score 3):

блин, посмотрел на пример своего кода и сразу понял! надо бы сделать в базовом классе виртуальный признак типа bool isClassic() и тогда буду иметь:

```
void Executor::run()
{
    //some code
    if(isClassic())
        runVirtual();
    else
        runAsyncVirtual();
    //some code
}
```

Иногда полезно просто четко и ясно сформулировать проблему чтоб увидеть ее решение. Всем большое спасибо, вы меня вывели на правильный путь!

```
/* можно было бы еще сделать отдельный объект для разных видов асинхронного запуска (напр. Runner), сделать его указатель членом Executor и пустить новую иерархию наследования по признаку "как запускать асинхронно", а не как совершать "само действие", но в том то и дело, что иногда сам по себе такой запуск и есть "само действие", например функции boost::asio вида async_xxx, запуск такой функции (в функции runVirtual) и есть само "основное" действие, и в ней же можно указать функцию, ожидающую ответ, то есть еще и разновидность Runner'a*/
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не называйте метод `isClassic()`. Лучше `isAsync()`

Comment: к этому и пришел в проекте